# asp.net mvc table naming question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, naming-conventions

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and see that tables should be named in a convention to allow the framework to work correctly.

I have to build a web front end in MVC based on existing tables with names I cannot change / control.

How do I build this into my MVC application, can I use this existing tables?

Thanks Paul

Comment: what do you mean "tables"? SQL Server? Are you using Entity Framework? Linq to Sql? NHibernate?

Comment: I think you are confusing your data access strategy with your front-end project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use an ORM, such as Entity Framework 4, and then bind the created entitys (pocos) to the MVC UI then you can do table/column mapping so you're not stuck with the names in the db.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

By "tables" you mean "database tables"? If so, ASP.NET MVC is not tied to a database, you can use whatever name you want. You define what will be the name convention of your tables.

By the way, if you already have all database schema working properly, you can look at the Entity Framework, it generates all your Data Access code and entities based on an existing schema.